# Android link a fragment activity to a framelayout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a mainActivity with a framelayout (fragment_container), I've my main Class that extends Activity, and some others that extend Fragment, its all okay in here.

Now I've two classes that extends FragmentActivity. How can I show this fragmentActivity in my framelayout (fragment_container)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the your class' extension to Fragment and not FragmentActivity. And if you did that, you can use the code below:

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frameHolder, fragment );
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't display an Activity inside another Activity. You can, however, display multiple Fragments inside a single FragmentActivity, which is what I think you want.

Simply change the two classes that subclass FragmentActivity to subclass Fragment. Then place those fragments inside your FrameLayout. For any method call that requires an activity in the Fragment, simply call `getActivity()` and you'll be good to go.

Take a look at the developer docs for Fragments for more information:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html